# Javascript getElementbyId works once but not twice?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to get a table cell that can turn into textbox when we click on it, so that we can fill it and then the text is added to the cell.

There is my JavaScript function:

```
$(".cellConsigne").click(function () {
    var numId = this.id.substring(24);
    document.getElementById("MainContent_txtConsigne" + numId).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("MainContent_txtConsigne" + numId).focus();
});

$(".txtTab").focusout(function () {
    var numId = this.id.substring(23);
    document.getElementById("MainContent_cellConsigne" + numId).textContent = this.value;
    this.style.display = "none";
});
```

and my declaration of the cell and the textbox in C# code behind:

```
TableCell cell17 = new TableCell();
cell17.ID = "cellConsigne" + i.ToString();
cell17.CssClass = "cellConsigne";

TextBox txtConsignes = new TextBox();
txtConsignes.ID = "txtConsigne" + i.ToString();
txtConsignes.CssClass = "txtTab";
txtConsignes.BackColor = row.BackColor;

cell17.Controls.Add(txtConsignes);
```

So the problem is that this work fine the first time, I click, the textBox show and got the focus. I put the text in it and then leave the textBox and the text go to the cell.
But when I click on the cell for the second time I got a "reference null error" on the `document.getElementById("MainContent_cellConsigne" + numId)`.

Is the problem can come from the CSS class or from the modification of the style? I really don't know.

Comment: If you are using to jQuery you should stick to it. Not using `getElementById` would be a good start

Comment: learn to debug. Add `console.log(numId);` after the lines and see what you have. I bet that will show you the error.

Comment: Additionally you should save the object from the `getElementById` DOM query and don't do this operation twice.

Comment: I'm using visual studio so I got step by step debugging and the value of numId is the same each time.

Comment: I beleive the element with this id `"MainContent_cellConsigne" + numId` would be within this `.txtTab` class element. and since your hiding the element `.txtTab` , the elements your trying to read is not visible. you need to rework on your logic in this case

Comment: there is still the probleme even if I replace display style by visibility style.

Comment: Do you do a postback between the first time you click the cell and the second time?  Your ID could be changing.

Comment: No, I don't do a postback between the two click and the ID stay the same. I don't know why it won't work. The display style option seems to be a good idea but I made nearly the same thing with a div who pop up when the mouse enter in a div and I didn't got that problem.

Comment: Just curious, did you try this in multiple browsers?  For instance, does it fail in IE, but not in Chrome?  Also, please use "@-replies" to respond to people - otherwise, they won't know you've responded.  For instance, include @jadarnel27 anywhere in your comment to respond to me.

Comment: @jadarnel27 ok, sorry I'm new here. I try in firefox and google chrome but the textbox not even appears but the css did change. The other event of jquery work but not really like in ie, like the drag and drop who didn't trigger. But in that project it will only be run in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the issue!

When I do that

```
document.getElementById("MainContent_cellConsigne" + numId).textContent = this.value;
```

it empty the cell from the controls inside it and after it add the text to the cell. So the textBox is not in the cell anymore.

I just add a label in the cell and add the text from the textBox to the label and that didn't empty the cell anymore.